# How is Anordnung pronounced?

Tags: pronunciation

As An-Or-d-nung or A-nor-d-nung? Similar questions always baffle me.

What is the general rule?

The problem is whether a composite word is pronounced separately.

Comment: It's a special kind of *Ordnung*, so it's pronounced *An-ord-nung*. German is rock-stable in splitting up words into syllables. Now try to split up *Staubecken*.

Comment: You can also look up the hyphenation, because that follows the syllabic structure: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Anordnung

Comment: @CarstenS: Well, not always, but in this case it does.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, I thought it does so except for a few exceptions which have become even fewer in number with the 'new' orthography.

Comment: @CarstenS: It's true, the most frequent deviations between hyphenation and syllables were systematic, but have been removed with the spelling reform (ck, st, and so on). And of course you're right, as it's not for nothing that the German term for *hyphenation* is *Silbentrennung*, i.e. syllable separation.

Comment: @Janka: Schlechtes Beispiel, weil mehrdeutig: 1. Hinter dem Staudamm erstreckt sich ein großes **Stau-becken.** 2. In einigen Ecken liegt Staub, in anderen nicht. Du solltest aber alle Ecken sauber machen. Warum hast du die drei verbliebenen **Staub-ecken** nicht geputzt?

Comment: I think that was Janka’s ‘joke’ ;)

Comment: Genau deshalb habe ich dieses Beispiel gebracht. Die Silbentrennung bleibt zwar auch bei zusammengesetzten Wörtern erhalten (das war die Frage), allerdings weiß man ja nicht unbedingt, aus welchen Teilwörtern sie bestehen.

Comment: An intereseting case is the pronunciation of "beobachten". Where I come from, everybody says "beo-bachten", but I heard some people say "beob-achten". I still don't know if this is a question of regional variance or whether those people (they were lecturers of german studies) individually 'corrected' the pronounciation to make it fit the rule.

Answer (score 3):

I could understand two possible hyphenations (and so pronunciations):

1 An-ord-nung
2 A-nord-nung

The first is correct.
The second is no proper German, although there is the word stem *nord* from *Norden* (*north*), but the suffix *-nung* does not fit. (There is a word *Nordung* = align to the direction north). And then the prefix *a-* (for something like a negotiation) does not give any sense to the word.

Similar word with other prefix:
Unordnung (Un-ord-nung)

Comment: Both pronunciations are proper German. They are just different regional pronunciations.

Comment: for which region A-nord-nung is a proper pronounciation?

Comment: The pronunciation *A-nord-nung* is common in Swiss Standard German. I do not know about other Southern varieties of Standard German. In Northern Germany Standard German, the pronunciation *An-ordn-ung* is common.

Comment: I never heard Swiss do pronounce against syllabification and split the syllables to move single sounds/characters to other syllables. they emphasize other than german (or austrian), but none splits syllables.

Comment: There is often not glottal stop in Swiss Standard German, cf. e.g. Ingrid Hove’s «Die Aussprache des Hochdeutschen in der Schweiz». Consequently, the syllabification appears to be different.

Answer (score 2):

**An**ordnung (I know how you feel, as I always have similar questions when it comes to English ...).  General rule: ask us.  You'll get a correct answer, and also some other wisdom along with it.  If it is urgent, ie you need to say the word *now*, you can also just to put the emphasis on the first syllable.

Comment: General rule: consult a dictionary. If you ask here without having consulted a dictionary you question is likely to be closed.

Answer (score 2):

The general rule for German pronunciation is that morphemes are pronounced distinctly. Where the morpheme boundary lies must be looked up in a dictionary, derived from your previous knowledge and context, or similar.

Taking your *Anordnung* example, the morphemes are *an-* and *Ordnung*. Thus, there is an audible separation between the two resulting in the pronunciation best being written as *An|ordnung* or *An-ordnung.*

While some typical prefixes *(an-, auf-, ab-, vor-, nach-, aus-, ein-* to name just a random sample) can be easily identified most of the time, it may get exponentially more difficult when dealing with compound words — to the point where context is needed to tell two possible options apart.

An often-cited case in point is *Wachstube.* This word can be interpreted as *Wachs-Tube* or as *Wach-Stube*, one being pronounced /waks|tu​ː​bə/ the other being /wax|ʃtu​ː​bə/.

Answer (score 1):

The official Authority on this is the Duden

Worttrennung: An|ord|nung

http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Anordnung

Comment: No, Duden is not the official Authority. Neither for orthography nor for Hyphenation. (For Orthography it is a document published by Rat für deutsche Rechtschreibung http://www.rechtschreibrat.com) Some words also have two or more possibilities like Wachstube (Wach-stu-be vs. Wachs-tu-be) or Eistempel (Ei-stem-pel vs. Eis-tem-pel) of which just one is listed in Duden.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the pronunciation of almost every German word on [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/). The page for *Anordnung* is: https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Anordnung

There is a section titled »*Aussprache*« (*pronunciation*), and in case of Anordnung it says:

> [ˈanˌʔɔʁdnʊŋ]

The high apostrophe (ˈ) means: The next syllable is stressed. The low Apostrophe (ˌ) means: The next syllable is also stressed, but it is not the most stressed syllable in the word. There is no extra sign for unstressed syllables, which means, the last syllable of Anordnung is unstressed.

You can find a description of the other symbols here: [International Phonetic Alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet)

---

**How do you know how many syllables? And where are the borders between syllables?**

It is almost the same in all languages of the world: The core of a syllable is a vowel. So as a rule of thumb, around every vowel is one syllable, and the border between syllables is somewhere where the consonants are. Therefore just »d« alone never can be a syllable, because there is no vowel.

»Anordnung« has three vowels: [a], [ɔ] and [ʊ] and since there are no diphthongs in this word, »Anordnung« must have three syllables.

You can read more about syllables on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllable).